# Calculating statistical significance on survey results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, survey

Consider a single survey question: "What is your favourite color"
with 4 possible responses: blue, green, red, yellow

If I've collected 100 responses:

- blue 20
- green 40
- red 35
- yellow 5

How do I calculate/test whether these results are statistically significant.
For example, given the 100 answers, is green (40) statistical different than red (35). Is blue (20) statistical different than red (35)

I need to collect more data before I make decisions based on this data?

Edit: My current thinking is to do a one-way chi-squared test to calculate statistical significance. Would this be the right way to go about this?

Comment: Your question, "How do I test whether these results are statistically significant?" is a bit vague unless you state explicitly what hypothesis you are testing. I assume you meant the null hypothesis to be that the four colors are equally favored. Then Yes.

Comment: You need to specify in the question (add it as an edit) *what is the hypothesis you want to test*. Or do you really want to test if the max in the data can be taken as the max in the population? or ... ?

Answer (score 8):

**One-way chi-squared test.** For the sample data you provided, the null hypothesis that
all colors are equally favored is strongly rejected with
P-value near $0.$ That is, it would be almost impossible to
observe these four counts if colors were equally favored.

The chi-squared statistic $Q = \sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{(X_i = E_i)^2}{E_i},$
has approximately a chi-squared distribution with $\nu = 4-1 = 3$ degrees
of freedom, where $E_i = \frac 14\sum_{i=1}^4 X_i,$ provided that all $E_i \ge 5.$ Computation in R:

```
X = c(20, 40, 35, 5)
E = c(25, 25, 25, 25)
Q = sum((X-E)^2/E);  Q
[1] 30
1 - pchisq(Q, 3)
[1]  1.380057e-06
```

Any value of $Q$ exceeding the critical value $c = 7.815$ leads to
rejection of the null hypothesis that colors are equally likely to be
chosen, at the 5% level of significance.

```
qchisq(.95, 3)
[1] 7.814728
```

Most statistical software programs have procedures to
do such a test. In R it is called `chisq.test`; the "given probabilities" are taken to be equal, unless you specify otherwise.

```
chisq.test(X)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  X
X-squared = 30, df = 3, p-value = 1.38e-06
```

To see the expected counts used for the test, you can use `$`-notation:

```
chisq.test(X)$exp
[1] 25 25 25 25
```

**Sample size for desired power.** At the end of your question
it seems you are wondering whether 100 subjects are sufficient
to find differences among the probabilities of choosing various
colors. That depends on 'effect size'. More specifically, it depends
on the pattern of unequal probabilities you want to be reasonably
sure to detect.

There are [formulas](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Chi-Square_Tests.pdf) (based on a pattern of probabilities), which use the non-central chi-squared distribution to compute power for a given sample size.

At a more elementary mathematical level, one can use simulation to approximate the power of the
one-way chi-squared test at the 5% level, given a particular pattern of probabilities.
Specifically, if you want to distinguish between the null pattern
$(.25, .25, .25, .25)$ and the alternative pattern $(.1, .3, .3, .3),$ then
the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis (power) with $n = 100$ subjects
is above 90%.  However, if the alternative pattern is $(.2, .2, .3, .3),$
then the power is less than 40%. These simulations find the proportion
of rejections among 100,000 tests.

```
set.seed(2021)
pr = c(.1, .3, .3, .3)
pv = replicate(10^5, chisq.test(
 tabulate(sample(1:4, 100, rep=T, p=pr), nbins=4) )$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.91649     # aprx power of test at 5% level

set.seed(915)
pr = c(.2, .2, .3, .3)
pv = replicate(10^5, chisq.test(
 tabulate(sample(1:4, 100, rep=T, p=pr), nbins=4))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.35614
```

Here is some detail for *one* of the 100,000 tests in the second
scenario.

```
choices = sample(1:4, 100, rep=T, p=pr);  choices
  [1] 4 2 1 2 3 4 4 4 1 2 4 1 2 4 2 1 3 4 1 4 4 3 3 2 3
 [26] 3 3 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 2 3 4 2 1 1 2 3 2 4 2 4
 [51] 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 3 4 2 3 1 3 3 2 4 4 4 3 1 1 4
 [76] 2 1 4 4 4 4 3 1 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 3 1 3 1 4 4
x = tabulate(choices, nbin=4);  x
[1] 20 19 29 32
chisq.test(x)$p.val
[1] 0.1688915     # not rejected
```

Comment: +1. Very clear explanations. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

"Statistical significance" has very little meaning and this is not a place for hypothesis testing.  The answer to the question of whether probabilities of colors are equal to certain set values can already be assumed to be false.  An appropriate approach is interval estimation, e.g., provide "best guess" point estimates (observed proportions) and their compatibility (confidence) intervals.  The [Wilson confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) is the most exact of the easy to use traditional frequentist approaches.  In R you can get this from the `Hmisc` package `binconf` function, and I'll bet that it's implemented in many other systems.